# How Gulp + sourcemaps work for debugging

Tags: build, gulp, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-minify

So I just got set up with Gulp yesterday and after a rocky start I'm well on my way to automating build processes, but I decided to try and do something a **teensy** bit trickier and suddenly hit another wall.

My desired output is to have a minified javascript file which I can serve to the browser and, upon inspecting in Chrome or Firefox, see the original source code. Pretty simple, right?

I currently have the following in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('minify', function() {
    gulp.src('./sources/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(minify({
        ext:{
            src:'.js',
            min:'.min.js'
        }
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js'));
});
```

This successfully generates the sourcemaps in `./www/js/maps/` and it puts the following at the bottom of the **uncompressed** files:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=maps/<whatever>.js.map
```

However it does not append such a comment to the bottom of the **compressed** files. As such when I open these files in a browser it's unable to show me the original source.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
gulp.task('minify', function() {
    gulp.src('./sources/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(minify({
        ext:{
            src:'.js',
            min:'.min.js'
        }
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps', {
      addComment: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/js'));
});
```